# What is the meaning of "im Gegenteil" in the following context?

Tags: meaning

> +++ Hätten wir dann **weniger** gestritten?
>
> +++ Ganz **im Gegenteil**.

I'm torn between two possible interpretations of *im Gegenteil*. The expression is obviously used in relation to the word *weniger*, but does this mean:

> (A): No, we would have argued ***quite a lot***, contrary to your expectation.
>
> or (B): Yes, in that (hypothetical) case, we would ***not*** have argued ***at all***, contrary to how things actually stand at the moment (where we do fight a lot).

Comment: Only interpretation A is possible. That is because *im Gegenteil* can only negate the preceding sentence as a whole. Your second interpretation plays around with the first sentence instead of taken it as set. Is this a question about German language at all?

Answer (score 1):

Interpretation A) is the right one.